# Create a list from string, in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like this (with n number of elements):

```
input = 'John, 16, random_word, 1, 6, ...'
```

How can I convert it to a list like this? I would like ',' to be a separator.

```
output = [John, 16, random_word, 1, 6, ...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you mean `output = ['John', '16', 'random_word', '1', '6', ...]`? you could just split it like `output = inpt.split(', ')`. this also removes the whitespaces after `,`.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, thanks! Considering that my string will always be formatted so that space only comes after the comma.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `input.split(',')` but as others have noted, you'll have to deal with leading and trailing spaces. Possible solutions are:

- without regex:

  ```
  In [1]: s = 'John, 16, random_word, 1, 6, ...'

  In [2]: [subs.strip() for subs in s.split(',')]
  Out[2]: ['John', '16', 'random_word', '1', '6', '...']
  ```

  What I did here is use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), in which I created a list whose elements are made from the strings from `s.split(',')` by calling the [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method on them.
  This is equivalent to

  ```
  strings = []
  for subs in s.split(','):
      strings.append(subs)
  print(subs)
  ```
- with [regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

  ```
  In [3]: import re

  In [4]: re.split(r',\s*', s)
  Out[4]: ['John', '16', 'random_word', '1', '6', '...']
  ```

Also, try not to use `input` as variable name, because you are thus shadowing [the built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input).

You can also just `split` on `', '`, but you have to be absolutely sure there's always a space after the comma (think about linebreaks, etc.)

Comment: Could you please explain the "without regex" steps a bit more in detail? I can't seem to replicate what you did. Please note that I've been learning programming for only a week or so. And thank you!

Comment: @SlobodanStevic I tried to outline the process, feel free to ask more specific questions. Note that what I showed was from an interactive `ipython` session, and if you try putting this in a script, you won't see any output unless you explicitly `print` something.

Answer (score 1):

Use the split function.

```
output = input.split(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, simply do:

```
output = input.split(',')
```

You will probably need to trim each resulting string afterwards since `split` does not care about whitespaces.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Thanks! I didn't explain well, but you got it right. This does what I wanted, now just to remove those spaces.